# Update person name in database

Tags: c#, api, controller

Can someone review this implemented solution and provide commentary the code is working well but will need refactor and improve this code.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;

namespace PersonUpdateApi.Controllers
{
    public class PersonUpdateModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NewFirstname { get; set; }
        public string NewSurname { get; set; }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class PersonController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private Logger _logger;

        public PersonController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public void LogUpdateRequest(PersonUpdateModel p)
        {
            _logger.Info($"Update request received. Person ID: {p.Id}, New forename = {p.NewFirstname}, New surname = {p.NewSurname}");
        }

        private void LogSuccessfulUpdate(PersonUpdateModel p)
        {
            _logger.Info($"Update request was successful for Person ID: {p.Id}.");
        }

        private void LogException(PersonUpdateModel p, Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Info($"An error occurred when updating the person. Person ID: {p.Id}, New forename = {p.NewFirstname}, New surname = {p.NewSurname}", ex);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Update(PersonUpdateModel p)
        {
            _logger = new Logger();
            LogUpdateRequest(p);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.NewFirstname))
                return BadRequest("There was no firstname specified");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.NewSurname))
                return BadRequest("There was no surname specified");

            if (p.Id < 1)
                return BadRequest("Invalid person ID");

            string dbConnectionStr = _config.GetValue<string>("Database:ConnectionString");
            int dbTimeoutInSeconds = 120;

            try
            {
                string updateSql = "UPDATE People SET Firstname = '" + p.NewFirstname + "', Surname = '" + p.NewSurname + "' WHERE PersonId = " + p.Id;

                Database db = new Database();
                db.ExecuteNonReturningQuery(dbConnectionStr, updateSql, dbTimeoutInSeconds);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                LogException(p, ex);
                return BadRequest("There was an error updating the person in the database. Please try again later.");
            }

            LogSuccessfulUpdate(p);
            return Ok("The update was successful");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### `PersonUpdateModel`

- Depending on how sophisticated your Person model is, you might need to consider to extend your update model with *middle name*
- Prefixing first name and surname with `new` is unnecessary

  - since you don't have other properties with `old` or `current`
- Using a consistent naming help eligibility

  - first name and last name
  - forename and surname
  - given name and family name

### `PersonController`

#### `ctor`

- Most of the time a class-wide logger is the preferred approach
- If you register your `Logger` inside your DI then you can receive an instance of it via the constructor

#### `LogXYZ`

- These methods (most probably) should not need to be `public`

#### `LogUpdateRequest`

- This can be extracted into a [request logger middleware](https://blog.elmah.io/asp-net-core-request-logging-middleware/)

#### `LogSuccessfulUpdate`

- Most of the time the successful operation logs are pointless

  - You perform logging primarily to help yourself during debugging (so the exceptional cases are the interesting one)
  - If you want to use the successful logs to calculate **success-failure ratio** then consider to introduce two counters instead

#### `LogException`

- `Info` might not be the best severity level here

  - `Warning` or `Error` might be more suitable

#### `Update`

- Naming a parameter to `p` is not really a good idea

  - try to find more expressive name
- Your `p` variable might be `null` if you receive a malformed request body

  - You should check whether or not it is `null` before you try to access any of its member otherwise it will throw `NullReferenceException`
  - The request will fail miserable inside your `LogUpdateRequest` method, so you will not have any log message about it
- Retrieving the connection string all the time most probably not needed

  - If it does not change dynamically then you can retrieve that value inside the constructor for example
- `dbTimeoutInSeconds` could be marked as `const`
- Performing database operation from the controller is not really a good practice

  - Try to introduce layers, like service and repository each with its own responsibility
- `updateSql`: string concatenation of sql DML is prone to SQL Inject

  - The preferred way is to use [command parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)
- Creating a `Database` instance manually might not be the best approach

  - You should consider to register that as well inside the DI
- Returning with `BadRequest` in case of exception is misleading

  - `StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)` might be more suitable
  - Please do not pass the `ex` to the `StatusCode` method call, because it might reveal system internals which can be valuable for malicious users

Answer (score 2):

#### Quick remarks (in addition to Peter Csala's review):

- Your controller does too much. [Keep it thin and lean](https://makingloops.com/visualizing-thin-controllers/), and create other classes to implement the logic etc. For instance, [use MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR).

  Right now your controller is 80-something lines and yet there is only one actual method doing anything; and honestly it is doing something simple. Your approach will become unmaintainable once you need to apply complicated business logic.
- Don't create a method to log a single line unless that method will be used in many places. (And even then there are often better solutions.)
- [Use Dapper](https://dapper-tutorial.net/) instead of ADO.NET.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate your comments i will refactor them straight away